# how to implement gesture to a button on android?

Tags: android, gesture

I have a button (button1) and two sound (sound1, sound2), I want to implement a gesture to this button. if Button1 is clicked, then the sound is sound1 but if Button1 is touched by the gesture, the sound is sound2. to handle the sound, I use a SoundManager class. to handle touch I use multitouch class.

```
public class MyActivity extends MultiTouch {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

    SoundManager.getInstance();
    SoundManager.initSounds(this);
    SoundManager.loadSounds();

    Button Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SoundManager.playSound(1, 1);
        }
    });
     }

 public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        SoundManager.cleanup();
    }
```

}

Thank you so much

Comment: your code looks fine ....what's the problem that you are facing?

Comment: have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

Comment: the problem is I want to add gesture on button1 to call sound2. if i use the code above, I can only call sound1 by the click. I want, when I click button1 I want the sound is sound1 but when I touched button1 using gesture, then the sound is sound2.

--Using Google Translate--

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference between click and touch.
But if you want to implement both, you have to make a trick to make it work.

For the System it is hard to decide laying the finger on a button, if you want to "click" or "touch" it. To controll this, you can get the time, the button is clicked/touched/whatever...

for example:
If you click/touch/whatever a Button you start counting, if you stopped clicking/touching/whateevring you stopped the countig. After that its easy: if(time < 1s)  else

Beware, that it would be a good idea to have a Click-Listener and TouchListener with the same code in it and just decide, using the counting stuff.

I've implemeted it already at it works perfectly!

Comment: in ouTouch you can handle all other events fling scroll or single tap double tap.. But onClick only handle click

Answer (score 0):

You can for exemple use a GestureListener (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#5307216038506006379) and handle the differents events or type of gesture for your button (touch, tap, swipe...)

Answer (score -1):

dynamically creating button would cause problems.but if make the buttons in you xml file and then set on